# How to fix ReferenceError: primordials is not defined in node v13.12.0

Tags: node.js, kraken.js

I am trying to install krakenjs using the guide available on http://krakenjs.com/
when i am trying to run **yo kraken** this command i get this error

```
fs.js:39
} = primordials;
    ^

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:39:5
    at req_ (C:\Users\KIIT\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-kraken\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (C:\Users\KIIT\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-kraken\node_modules\natives\index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\KIIT\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-kraken\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
```

using following versions
node: 13.12.0
gulp
CLI version: 2.2.0
Local version: 4.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `generator-kraken` module seems to be using `natives` as a dependency. The `natives` module has been [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/natives), and doesn't behave consistently across all versions of node.

You could use Node v10 to run generator (`yo kraken` command). Yomen generator (`yo`) only spits out static code. Once your code has been generated you can return back to node 13, if required. Since kraken itself doesn't have any dependency on natives, you shouldn't face any problem running the generated code with node 13. You can use `nvm` to quickly switch between versions of node, if you aren't already.

Another viable option would be to skip the 'generator' altogether and start with one the examples repos mentioned on [Kraken home page here](http://krakenjs.com/#examples). You could clone one of those repositories and adapt it to your use. Or, use them as reference and create your own setup from scratch.

Comment: thanks bro worked like charm i used nvm to switch node versions to 10.0 and it worked, thanks a lot